# Knockout JS template not showing an object property in an observable array?

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js

I had working code that looked like this:

(This variable declared outside the view model.)

```
var urlTemplate = "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=XXX&type=card";
```

(This array defined inside the view model.)

```
 self.deck = [
   { id: 1, name: "Plains", mvId: 73963, imageUrl: urlTemplate.replace('XXX', '73963') },
   { id: 2, name: "Forest", mvId: 174928, imageUrl: urlTemplate.replace('XXX', '174928') }
 ];
```

(This was the template.)

```
 <div id="hand" data-bind="foreach: hand">
     <div class="cardInHand">
         <img height="150" data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl, alt: name }" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

As I mentioned, this worked well and the template correctly showed the image listed in the source.

However, instead of adding an anonymous type to the array I added a new view model called "card".  This change was mainly made to support other functions related to a card didn't make sense in the first view model.  Card looks like this:

```
var card = function (id, name, multiverseId) {

    self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable();
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.multiverseId = ko.observable();

    // other methods defined here ...

    self.imageUrl = ko.computed(function() {
        return imageUrlTemplate.replace('XXX', multiverseId);
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

}
```

Then changed the array in the first view model to add cards like this:

```
    self.deck = [
        new card(3, "Plains", 269637),
        new card(4, "Forest", 376343)
    ];
```

And finally the template to be this:

```
 <div id="hand" data-bind="foreach: hand">
    <div class="cardInHand">
       <img height="150" data-bind="attr: { src: $data.imageUrl, alt: $data.name }" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

It took a while to get rid of the obvious javascript errors, but once they were cleared the final result simply didn't display anything.

When I opened Chrome's debugging tool, went to Elements, and found the div id 'hand' the computed element simply showed the literal template--no replacements with the actual value.  In the original working version it show the template but also had the src and alt values properly filled in.

If I remove the $data from the template I get javascript errors.

How do I get the binding to work now that I have these card objects?

I added [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WA3eQ/3/) to demonstrate what I'm doing. When clicking New Game you can see the old code work but not the newer version.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the shown code here, but how you "clone" your cards in the `resetBoardState` method. Because the `JSON.strigify(JSON.parse(self.deck))` does not re-create your `card` objects so your observable properties will be lost. If you don't need a real deep clone you can use `self.deck.splice(0)`: http://jsfiddle.net/uKNQB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nemesv said, you don't need that JSON.strigify(JSON.parse(self.deck)).

I just removed it from your fiddle and it all seems to work ok, but Nevesv's splice looks like a good solution to copy the deck into the library (I guess so the library can be shuffled without losing the originaly deck order or something?)

Another problem you had in the code, was actually because you were only creating 5 cards in the first deck, but your self.mulliganCount property was set to 7, so when you drew a hand it wasn't find enough cards so was adding a null object into your deck, which then couldn't be rendered and so you got the

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "attr: function (){return { src:$data.imageUrl,alt:$data.name} }"
```

Message: Cannot read property 'imageUrl' of undefined

You don't need the $data on there either, so I removed that from my fiddle below.

The fix was to either change the mulligan setting to 5 or add 2 new cards to the first deck....I added 2 new cards:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jiggle/bT8Ch/)

```
        { id: 10, name: "Hopeful Eidolon", multiverseId: 373616, imageUrl: imageUrlTemplate.replace('XXX', '373616') },
        { id: 10, name: "Skylasher", multiverseId: 369083, imageUrl: imageUrlTemplate.replace('XXX', '369083') }
```

Comment: I see. Sorry about the bad Fiddle... it was pretty late when I put it up there and the clone issue was disguising the card count issue.  The reason the clone is there is because the deck should be immutable and only gets created once.  The library can change contents and order many times. It seemed a good idea to separate the two.